# Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4 - when fetch link Ajax [GAS]

Tags: json, ajax, google-apps-script, http-get, urlfetch

First, I have to apologize for my poor English skill I am using Google Apps Script.
I'm trying to get JSON data from AJAX link but **sometimes** error occurs
**Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4**

I know the problem here is the data return form "**HTML**" while i expect "**JSON**"

I trying

**My Script**

```
async function getJSON () { 
const myHeaders = {
'cache' : 'no-cache',
'pragma': 'no-cache',
'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
'accept': 'text',
'dataType' : 'text',
'contentType': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
};
const myInit = {
  muteHttpExceptions: true,
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
};
const url = "https://www.xxxx.xxx/xxxxxxx/?ajax=xxxxxxx"
const content = await UrlFetchApp.fetch(url ,myInit).getContentText();
const obj = JSON.parse(content);
....
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem as you say is that sometimes the response is an HTML, which generates that when the [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function is called, an error arises because the response does not contain a valid JSON.

This error comes from the server, so there is not much you can do about it. One way to handle the error is with a [try-catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) block, which is common practice in asynchronous fetch.

For example:

```js
async function getJSON() {
  try {
  const myHeaders = {
    'cache': 'no-cache',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'accept': 'text',
    'dataType': 'text',
    'contentType': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  };
  const myInit = {
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: myHeaders,
  };
  const url = "https://www.xxxx.xxx/xxxxxxx/?ajax=xxxxxxx"
  const content = await UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, myInit).getContentText();
  const obj = JSON.parse(content);
  // ...
  } catch (err) {
    console.log({
      err
    })
  }
}
```